# Reference request: Intersection number using derived tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I just learned there is a version of definition of intersection number using derived tensor product to avoid the moving lemma. I only know intersection theory as presented in Fulton's book. Does anyone know any reference about the derived version of intersection number? Probably this is discussed in SGA 6. But as I don't know a keyword nor have a searchable copy of SGA 6, it may not be the most ideal reference for me.

Comment: It's just Serre's intersection formula: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Serre+intersection+formula Recall what the definition of the derived tensor product is.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks!

Comment: @AlexYoucis do you want to post your comment as an answer?